# Data retrieved from web service cannot be displayed due to special characters

Tags: java, android, special-characters, spannablestring

I'm trying to display a field out from a url but the field only displayed up the point where special characters come in. For example, the data is:

**What is the Social Good Summit about?</strong><p> <p>The Social Good Summit worldwide is about bringing together social enterprises and charities with technology and social media companies to explore how to tackle some of the world&#39;s biggest difficulties.**

But when displayed, it only display:

**What is the Social Good Summit about?**

I tried using the SpannableStringBuilder but it still don't work. This is the sample code:

```
public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    static final String URL = "http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?app_key=42t54cX7RbrDFczc&location=singapore";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_EVENT = "event"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_URL = "url";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
    static final String KEY_START_TIME = "start_time";
    static final String KEY_STOP_TIME = "stop_time";
    static final String KEY_VENUE_NAME = "venue_name";
    static final String KEY_COUNTRY_NAME = "country_name";

    String regex = "</{0,1}.+?>";
    String replacement = "";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_EVENT);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_URL));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, "Description: " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
            map.put(KEY_START_TIME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_START_TIME));
            map.put(KEY_STOP_TIME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_STOP_TIME));
            map.put(KEY_VENUE_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_VENUE_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_COUNTRY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COUNTRY_NAME));
            // adding HashList to ArrayList

            menuItems.add(map);


        }



        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { KEY_TITLE,  KEY_COUNTRY_NAME,
                        KEY_VENUE_NAME, KEY_START_TIME }, new int[] {
                        R.id.title, R.id.countryName, R.id.venueName,
                        R.id.startTime });

        SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(KEY_DESC);

        TextView contentView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
        contentView.setText(stringBuilder);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the HTML.fromHTML(String source) method:

public static Spanned fromHtml (String source)

Provide it the String you mentioned above..

Comment: I don't really quite get what you mean, can you please demo it out so that I can refer to it more? Thank you.

Comment: Instead of `contentView.setText(stringBuilder);` try using `contentView.setText(Html.fromHtml(stringBuilder.toString()));` and check.